# Swapping Colors in Button-Template on pressed

Tags: wpf, templates, xaml, triggers, styles

I am trying to design a button-template, that swaps its colors, when pressed.

Unluckily I cant get it to work.

I am using the BorderBrush as a temporary variable. Most likely there are more sophisticated solutions possible.

Here is my code.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{StaticResource RahmenFarbe}" />
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource HintergrundFarbe}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                              Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                              ClipToBounds="True">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Foreground}"
                                    x:Name="ButtonBorder"
                                    CornerRadius="25"
                                    BorderThickness="4"
                                    Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Background}"
                                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <TextBlock  x:Name="ButtonTextBlock"
                                            Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Foreground}"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="myContentPresenter"
                                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                        Value="{Binding Mode=OneTime, Path=Foreground}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                        Value="{Binding Mode=OneTime, Path=Background}" />
                                <Setter Property="Background"
                                        Value="{Binding Mode=OneTime, Path=BorderBrush}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers >

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards Sebastian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Finally understood what you really wanted to do. Here is how you get it done. Bind to the `TemplatedParent`'s `Background` and `Foreground` and set `TargetName` in the setters. This way, the source for the colors will always stay the same and you can easily swap them

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="ButtonBorder"
                Property="Background"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Foreground}" />
        <Setter TargetName="ButtonTextBlock"
                Property="Foreground"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Optionally, you can also change the `Bindings` in your `Template` from

```
Background="{Binding Path=Background,
                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                    AncestorType=Button,
                                                    AncestorLevel=1}}"
```

To just

```
Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
```

Comment: I absolutely agree.  But an other thing I like to archive is, when I change the colors in a button the behaviour (swapping) stays the same. It would look awkward, if the colors where hardcoded.  I fear i have to go for code behind  (borderbrush was just abused as a temporary variable)

Comment: But you are already setting Foreground and Background to static resources in the template, how was it abused? If you want to make it dynamic, use `DynamicResource` instead and override where you need to. Another option is to use Attached Properties. You won't be able to swap them by setting Foreground to Background as Background is changing as well

Comment: Actually I bind Fore- and Background of the Border to those of the Button. Those Bindings are supposed to be static. In the Trigger I change the button properties, so the other bindings should not be affected. I tried to avoid the automatic changes with "Binding Mode=OneTime". DynamicResource didn't work the way I intended, but perhaps I did not use it correctly.

Comment: @Athanviel: Updated, this time I think I understood your problem :)

Comment: Very nice, I didn't expect it to work, but it did. Tanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with codebehind.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{StaticResource RahmenFarbe}" />
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource HintergrundFarbe}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize"
                    Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight"
                    Value="Bold" />
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown"
                         Handler="vertauscheFarben" />
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseUp"
                         Handler="vertauscheFarben" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                              Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                              ClipToBounds="True">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Foreground}"
                                    x:Name="ButtonBorder"
                                    CornerRadius="25"
                                    BorderThickness="4"
                                    Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Background}"
                                    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <TextBlock  x:Name="ButtonTextBlock"
                                            Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=Foreground}"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="myContentPresenter"
                                                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
```

This is the CodeBehind

```
Private Sub vertauscheFarben(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    Dim Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    Dim Temp = Button.Foreground
    Button.Foreground = Button.Background
    Button.Background = Temp
End Sub
```

It is working, but I would prefer it within Xaml - so I won't mark this as answered.